# Unable to locate VBA notification macro via Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

so I have this code where its function is to send an email reminder to the user if the cell values in the range is equivalent to say, number x. Within the mail, it specifies directly which cell address has been changed. But the problem now is that, I was always prompted by the Macros table to select a macro to work on, and even worse, my macro was not present at all

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

            If Target.Column = 5 Then
                If Target.Row < 15 And Target.Row > 2 Then
                    If Target.value < 1 Then
                    Call mymacro(Target.Address)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End Sub

    Private Sub mymacro(theValue As String)


            Dim xOutApp As Object
            Dim xOutMail As Object
            Dim xMailBody As String
            Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
            xMailBody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                      "The value that changed is in cell: " & theValue

            On Error Resume Next
            With xOutMail
                .To = "email address"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "test succeeded"
                .Body = xMailBody
                .Display   'or use .Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set xOutMail = Nothing
            Set xOutApp = Nothing
        End Sub
```

The logic is okay ( I think ), but the main problem is, I was always prompted by Excel to select my Macro from the Macros table, and my macro was not even there! It's as if I have never created one at all. I tried to find some information regarding this issue, but its nowhere to be found. In other words, how can I make this macro work the way I wanted to? I have zero knowledge regarding VBA, so please excuse me if my question seems dumb. Do let me know if y'all need more information to understand the problem. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Are you using an XLSM file or XLAM file for your macro? The _Change needs to be part of an XLSM and it would probably be better to put the sub in an XLAM. (Add-In)

Comment: Neither of those Subs will show up in the "Run macro" dialog, since they both have parameters: only parameterless methods are listed.  Is this code in the worksheet code module?

Comment: @TimWilliams - subs with optional parameters as variants are listed.

Comment: @Jeeped - thanks for the correction

Comment: @braX I'm using a XLSM file. So are you saying that it would work if my Excel file is changed into the XLAM format? Mind if you share more with me? I'm really new at Excel :/

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your response!! This code is indeed in the worksheet code module.

Comment: Your code should run automatically when a you make a change on the worksheet - did you try putting a breakpoint and seeing if it hit?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes. I got it. It's not a macro after all. Once I saved the project, the code would run when I change the value within the target address. But, it couldn't run if it's updated automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "updated automatically"?

Comment: @Tim Williams The data that I want my VBA to work on is actually imported from a website. That's why it will change at a certain interval.

Comment: Imported how *exactly*?

Comment: The data is imported through the use of the web query function in Excel. I copied the URL of the website and paste it into the dialog of the "From Web" function in Excel. Then, I click "Load" and the data that is part of the URL will be converted into a table where it can be loaded to my Excel Worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

A [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel) is an event macro typically located on a private worksheet code sheet; not a public module code sheet. It also takes a non-optional, non-variant parameter. Sub procedures (what you call *macros*) are not listed in the Macros dialog when they require a non-variant parameter.

Comment: So, from what I can understand, I should take the whole Worksheet_Change code into a new separated module to get it working? Also, mind sharing some useful insights or links so that I can 'convert' my code into a non-variant parameter? Thank you lots!